# Services 3 Session authentication CSRF Validation with Persistent Log in

Tags: services, sessions, cookies, csrf

I am trying to use Services 7.x-3.11, the latest stable available to authenticate and access Drupal 7.34. Accessing from mobile devices with Native coding. I want to keep the user authenticated forever. Is it possible?

Here is the workflow i am following.

**First launch of app**

1. POST `/services/session/token` to retrieve CSRF Token
2. POST `myendpoint/system/connect` with *X-CSRF-Token* header
3. IF not Logged In Try Log in `/myendpoint/user/login`
4. Log in Success and keep `session_name=sessionid` in Cookie Varible

**Future Launches**

1. POST `/services/session/token` to retrieve CSRF Token
2. POST `myendpoint/system/connect` with *X-CSRF-Token* header along with previousely saved `session_name=sessionid` as *Cookie* Header

From this point I am getting **["CSRF validation failed"]** message. Am I missing something? Is the workflow correct?

Answer (score 2):

Evidently the workflow has been simplified.  I make a single call to `/user/login`.  Here is an example:

```
{
  "method": "POST",
  "url": "http://HOSTNAME/SERVICE_PATH/user/login",
  "headers": {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "Connection": "keep-alive"
  },
  "json": {
    "username": "USERNAME",
    "password": "PASSWORD"
  }
}
```

which returns:

```
Response: {
  "sessid": "waroHcB4h8rbU0yhZjh-zGLAquZYlpayC_kB38gx--I",
  "session_name": "SESSb4d5ba755bb4eb727d982993490e6681",
  "token": "MHT4hmagxHgf0lOYlkENGlTZGk2AZ96G3p3ZCCc2kvo",
...
}
```

Now the cookie is created by concating the session_name and sessid with the equal sign separating them.  The `X-CSRF-Token` header is simply the `token` in the response.  All future requests will reuse the `X-CSRF-Token:` and `Cookie: headers:`

Here is an example of a user profile request:

```
{
  "method": "POST",
  "url": "http://http://HOSTNAME/SERVICE_PATH/user/profile",
  "headers": {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "Connection": "keep-alive",
    "X-CSRF-Token": "MHT4hmagxHgf0lOYlkENGlTZGk2AZ96G3p3ZCCc2kvo",
    "Cookie": "SESSb4d5ba755bb4eb727d982993490e6681=waroHcB4h8rbU0yhZjh-zGLAquZYlpayC_kB38gx--I"
  }
}
```

Short answer: call `/user/login` once, set and reuse the **X-CSRF-Token:** and **Cookie:** headers for all future REST calls.

Comment: Thank you for posting this!  Virtually every piece of documentation available is out of date and doesn't reflect this.

Comment: I almost never use Drupal, and this information was so difficult to come by, that I sought out this question just to share.  Glad it helped and I have no idea if it remains relevant.

Answer (score 1):

Don't request for new CSRF token use the returned one for previous request.

You will find it in a key named `token` in the result returned.

Just request a new csrfCSRF token for the first time only.