# Persistent login using services

Tags: users, services

I am currently using [services](https://www.drupal.org/project/services) module and I have an android app. I am logging in using the login api, and I can go all the things provided by services. However after a few hours or few days, I can no longer use the api because it says I am not logged in. If there a way for me to keep the user logged in until they log out manually?

Comment: You can check for similar question.. http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/137603/services-3-session-authentication-csrf-validation-with-persistent-log-in, Unfortunately it has only one answer with is not accepted or up-voted, still you can try it out.

Comment: You have two options in the settings file that should allow you to configure the session timeout however you wish, session.gc_maxlifetime & session.cookie_lifetime.

Comment: Did you find answer for your question??

Comment: X-CSRF-Token can it be reused for all future api calls?